# Error when adding user to Chatter group with ConnectApi: Unknown user (System Code)

Tags: chatter, connect-api, chatter-groups

I have a trigger (onAfter insert User) that adds a newly created User (with Community profile assigned) to a public Chatter Group. For this I have used ConnectApi. The code is the following:

```
public void OnAfterInsert(User[] newObjects){

    Chatter_Group_Settings__c settings = Chatter_Group_Settings__c.getValues('sandbox');
    for(User u:newObjects){

        if(u.ProfileId == settings.Customer_Community_Profile_ID__c &&
           u.Add_to_Chatter_group__c == true){

               ConnectApi.GroupMember groupMember = ConnectApi.ChatterGroups.addMember('internal',settings.Chatter_Group_ID__c,u.Id);
           }
    } 
}
```

The problem is that, when I enable a Contact to be a Community User and thus, create the User record, I receive the following exception:

> UserTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Unknown user: (System Code)

I have tried Googling for similar problems, but haven't found anything. I have debugged values and seem correct (aside from the User ID, that is not committed to DB due to the exception).

Any clues on this one?

-Magandrez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**addMember(communityId, groupId, userId)**

> Adds the specified user to the specified group in the specified
>   community as a standard member. To execute this method, **the context
>   user must be the group owner or moderator.**

But in your case the context user is community user so this will not help you. You can make DML on

> CollabrationGroupMember

object to add user in the chatter group. it will solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, I get it, but creating and inserting a CollaborationGroupMember record gives a MIXED_DML_OPERATION error, so use @future and ends up with another problem I cannot resolve: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Now, the user inserting records is a System Admin and set as administrator of the Chatter Group. Any ideas?

Comment: @magandrez can you share your updated code.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/AX04e6wh

Comment: Please check your community group Id. i think you are giving wrong Id. Is this group created in community?

Comment: The problem was, I was using a Chatter Group ID from the standard UI, not from the community. Thanks for pointing out that.